# Django unique_together does not allow ForeignKey field across applications when syncdb is executed

Tags: python, sqlite, django-models, foreign-keys, unique

I'm trying to create a unique constraint on my `TranslationRequest` model listed below. `TranslationRequest` has a foreign key relationship with a `MachineTranslator` model, which exists in another Django application. When I try to run syncdb, I get the error: `Error: One or more models did not validate:
wt_articles.translationrequest: "unique_together" refers to translator, a field that doesn't exist. Check your syntax.`

When I remove `translator` from the `unique_constraint` specification, syncdb runs correctly. Note: I'm using Sqlite3 as my back-end database.

Here are the definitions of `TranslationRequest` and `SourceArticle`.

```
from wt_translation.models import MachineTranslator

class TranslationRequest(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(SourceArticle)
    target_language = models.ForeignKey(Language, db_index=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(_('Request Date'))
    translator = models.ForeignKey(MachineTranslator),
    status = models.CharField(_('Request Status'),
                              max_length=32,
                              choices=TRANSLATION_STATUSES)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("article", "target_language", "translator")

class SourceArticle(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('Title'), max_length=255)
    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, db_index=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(_('Import Date'), default=datetime.now())
    doc_id = models.CharField(_('Document ID'), max_length=512)
    source_text = models.TextField(_('Source Text'))
    sentences_processed = models.BooleanField(_('Sentences Processed'))
```

Here is the definition of `MachineTranslator`, in a different (but referenced Django application).

```
class MachineTranslator(models.Model):
    shortname = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)
    supported_languages = models.ManyToManyField(LanguagePair)
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'))
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=32, choices=TRANSLATOR_TYPES, default='Serverland'),
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(_('Refresh Date'), default=datetime.now())
    is_alive = models.BooleanField()
```

Not all of the dependencies have been included in this code sample. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont' know if it is a typo but i see s "," comma at the end of the line where you declare your translator = models.ForeignKey(MachineTranslator)

This is why maybe the attribute is ot seens

Comment: Thanks, that was a silly mistake. Apparently the comma only gave me an error when trying to access the field via unique_together. Otherwise, the field was usable elsewhere in the code.